# Calculate sum to five years back in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sum, date-arithmetic

I'm using select:

```
Select year, month, par1, par2, par3, value 
from table1
```

to produce this table:

[image]

Now, I want to calculate sum contains to five years back (it's 60 months).

Result should be as below:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: you month column is a string ? any date column or integer ?

Comment: How do you determine in which year the five year span should begin?

Comment: yes:  year, month, par1, par2, par3 are String

Comment: @Tim -> for each rows, you should got sum five years back, even for some rows you can't have data

Comment: why are the year & month in string ? is this the result of your existing query ?

Comment: they are set up in db, I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for you case, since the tables are in string, i uses a CTE to formulate a date column for the required calculation

```
; with
cte as
(
    select  *, date = convert(date, year + '-' + substring(month, 2, 2) + '-01', 121)
    from    table1
)
select  *
from    cte c
    outer apply
    (
        select  SumOfValue = sum(Value)
        from    cte x
        where   x.date  >= dateadd(month, -60, c.date)
        and x.date  <= c.date
    ) t
```

if you need the sum() to group by other column, add the condition to the OUTER APPLY query

EDIT 1 :

```
select  *
from    cte c
    outer apply
    (
        select  SumOfValue = sum(x.Value)
        from    cte x
        where   x.date  >= dateadd(month, -60, c.date)
        and     x.parameter1 = c.parameter1
        and     x.parameter2 = c.parameter2
        and     x.date      <= c.date
    ) t
```

Comment: dateadd(month, -60, c.date) -> should I here convert month to date? because I got error "'date' is not a recognized dateadd option."

Comment: you are using `SQL Server 2008` right ? that should work. If not in the cte use `date = convert(datetime, ...)`

Comment: date = convert(date or date = convert(datetime....are working, the error Im geting into: where  x.date  >= dateadd(date, -60, c.date)

Comment: should be `dateadd(month, -60, c.date)`

Comment: my query is correct. the `month` in the `dateadd()` is a key word. You should avoid using reserve word as column name. It will cause confusion.

Comment: ok, when I need to add other param, it should be put into other select?
as select SumOfValue = sum(Value), par1, par2??

Comment: what do you mean `another param` ?

Comment: param 3 = A or param 2 = PL

Comment: see Edit1. Is this what you want ?